# How to remove the Time portion from my DateTime Display

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I Have a pretty simple linq statemnt to pull up records from as database and i just wanted to know how to remove the Time portion from this? Tried many ways including .ToShortDateString, but it doesnt format correctly from the SQL Database, it just adds the numbers from what i can see. Below is my Linq Statement.

```
MSCDatabaseDataContext MSCDB = new MSCDatabaseDataContext();
            var q = from row in MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns
                    select new Campaign
                    {   
                        CampaignID = row.CampaignId,
                        CampaignName = row.CampaignName,
                        Target = Convert.ToInt32(row.Target),
                        Discount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Discount),
                        CampaignStartDatesS = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate) + " - " + Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate),
                        //CampaignSDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate),
                        //CampaignEDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate),
                        CurrentStatus = row.EndDate >= DateTime.Now && row.StartDate <= DateTime.Now ? "Active": row.StartDate >=  DateTime.Now ? "Pending": row.CampaignStatus == 4 ? "Archived": "Closed",
                        Uptake = Convert.ToInt32(row.Uptake),

                    };
```

Help Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you looking for something like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Date` property.

```
var today == DateTime.Now.Date; // there is a DateTime.Today as well, which does the same
```

> Gets the date component of this instance.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A new `DateTime` with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).